# Implementing Methods from Objective C Library with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, flir

I am trying to implement the following method in swift:

From the class FLIROneSDKImageReceiverDelegate, which is subclassed inside my ViewController class as so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FLIROneSDKImageReceiverDelegate,
    FLIROneSDKStreamManagerDelegate,
                        FLIROneSDKImageEditorDelegate{
```

Note that I have already created a bridging header etc.

In the FLIROneSDKImageReceiverDelegate header file:

```
- (void) FLIROneSDKDelegateManager:(FLIROneSDKDelegateManager *)delegateManager didReceiveBlendedMSXRGBA8888Image:(NSData *)msxImage imageSize:(CGSize)size;
```

Am I wrong in thinking that this is the correct way to implement this function?

```
func FLIROneSDKDelegateManagerdidReceiveBlendedMSXRGBA8888ImageimageSize(delegateManager: FLIROneSDKDelegateManager!, msxImage: NSData, size: CGSize){
```

Note that FLIROneSDKDelegateManager is a class.

Comment: doesn't Xcode tell you the missing method name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, but try this:

```
func FLIROneSDKDelegateManager(delegateManager: FLIROneSDKDelegateManager!, didReceiveBlendedMSXRGBA8888Image msxImage: NSData!, imageSize size: CGSize) {

    // method imp

}
```

Comment: This fails because FLIROneSDKDelegateManager is both a class and the name of the function and it's using the class in the function parameters.

Comment: This answer looks correct to me.  What error message do you get.

Comment: Huh that's interesting. It seems to complain that the `FLIROneSDKDelegateManager` class isn't found when I actually try to compile it. Changing `delegateManager` to `id` in Objective-C and `AnyObject` in Swift seems to get it to compile and conform to the protocol. Would that maybe be a workaround @Laxsnor ?

Comment: I switched the swift to this:    `func FLIROneSDKDelegateManager(delegateManager: AnyObject!, didReceiveBlendedMSXRGBA8888Image msxImage: NSData!, imageSize size: CGSize) { `
- is that what you had in mind? It doesn't compile now complaining that it conflicts with the objective c header.

Comment: @Laxsnor Iff you can alter the Objective-C protocol header those two should work nicely together (nothing should be impacted by it). If you don't have write access to the protocol then obviously this isn't an option though.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by modifying the Objective C header to `- (void) FLIROneSDKDelegateManager:(NSObject *)delegateManager didReceiveBlendedMSXRGBA8888Image:(NSData *)msxImage imageSize:(CGSize)size;` and the swift to: `func FLIROneSDKDelegateManager(delegateManager: NSObject!, didReceiveBlendedMSXRGBA8888Image msxImage: NSData!, imageSize size: CGSize) {`

Comment: The problem seems to be related to FLIR people ignoring convention that functions should start with a lower case letter, since their company name is all caps.  This causes a conflict between the class and the function, but I am not sure if this is acceptable or if it is a bug in Swift.  It may be worth reporting to Apple. Changing the function signature to `flirOneSDKDelegateManager...` avoids the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Laxsnor's solution in the comments on the answer by @aaron-wojnowski helped me too, thanks both.

**To consolidate:**

The problem is a conflict created by the name `FLIROneSDKDelegateManager` being used as a both a class name and a function name - which seems to be OK in Objective-C but not in Swift.

Replacing the class `FLIROneSDKDelegateManager` with `NSObject` in the function parameter seems to solve the problem without side-effects. This has to be done in both the Objective-C protocol header file and the Swift delegate class source file.

**NOTE** I also found this same solution applied more broadly to Swift-*ify* the entire FLIROneSDK at https://github.com/jruhym/flirmebaby.

Happy developing for FLIROne on Swift. (I'm new to FLIROne and relatively new to Swift so apologies if my language isn't quite precise enough.)